# How to use Multiple mcp23017 chips with the adafruit mcp23017.h library

Tags: arduino, i2c

I have been experimenting with I2C and the mcp23017 IO expander chip for my arduino ATMega2560 as I would rather use the IO on the arduino its self for other things I am just figuring out how to use the adafruit mcp23017.h library and cant figure out how to address multiple mcp23017 chips and how to use there pins individually this is the code from the button library that I editied.

I want to be able to address the individual chips and the pins I was not quite sure if in the setup that the pin modes for the IO go up sequentially from 0 past 15 if multiple chips are connected and addressed in code. For example if the first chip is addressed as 0x20 and the IO number count is from 0 - 15 if I added and addressed another chip as 0x21 will that count go from 0 - 15 to 0 - 31.

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include "Adafruit_MCP23017.h"

//pin 1 and 0 are mcp pins not arduino IO pins

Adafruit_MCP23017 mcp;

void setup() {  
mcp.begin();      // use default address 0

mcp.pinMode(0, INPUT);
mcp.pinMode(1, OUTPUT);
Serial.begin(9600);

pinMode(13, OUTPUT);  // use the p13 LED as debugging
}



void loop() {
// The LED will 'echo' the button
digitalWrite(13, mcp.digitalRead(0)); //Writes pin 13 to the reading of pin    0
mcp.digitalWrite(1, mcp.digitalRead(0)); //Writes pin 1 to the reading of 0
if(mcp.digitalRead(1) == HIGH){ //if pin 1 == high serialprint led whent   high
Serial.println("Led whent HIGH");
}
}
```

Comment: *"if I added and addressed another chip as 0x21 will that count go from 0 - 15 to 0 - 31."* If you have more than one chip available, why not simply try it out?

Comment: well i don't know how to address the chip as 0x20 or 0x21 looking through the header code for the library it seems set the default address to 0x20

Comment: Ok, I've never used the mcp23017 with an arduino before but on the raspberry pi, it's pretty easy to use `i2cset` from the `i2c-tools` package to manually write to the input/output registers that determine the direction of bank A and bank B. You then set or read all pins on either side in one write/one byte. Anyway, check this line: `mcp.begin(); // use default address 0`. It gives me the impression that you can provide a number/an address to `mcp.begin();`; e.g. `mcp.begin(0x20);` or `mcp.begin(32);`

Comment: `void Adafruit_MCP23017::begin(uint8_t addr)` <-- Here, you can supply an address to overwrite the default (0). From [Adafruit_MCP23017.cpp](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/adafruit/Adafruit-MCP23017-Arduino-Library/master/Adafruit_MCP23017.cpp). Apparently, it uses decimal 0-7 as addresses, not hex. `mcp.begin(0x20)` should be `mcp.begin(0)`, `mcp.begin(1)`, etc.

Comment: Would I implement the" void Adafruit_MCP23017::begin(uint8_t addr)" into the header file or the actual code on my arduino I am kind of confused I am only really new to arduino.

Comment: And like Vladimir Tsykunov stated _"By default the library doesn't support multiple chips"_ so I dot now think that adding this would help very much more or less make the whole code more confusing.

Comment: @ChrisPlusPlus i was mistaken, was thinking about other library. now I see the lib supports multiple chips.

Comment: @ChrisPlusPlus *"Would I implement the" void Adafruit_MCP ..."* No, I just found that line in the library source code which confirms what I wrote in my first comment; i.e.  *"that you can provide a number/an address to mcp.begin();"*. If you simply write `mcp.begin();` (no address given), the library defaults to address 0 (which is translated to something hexadecimal by the library; probably 0x20). If you write `mcp.begin(1);`, the address 1 (which is probably hex 21) will be used instead.

Comment: So does that mean that I will not have to change any of the library code?

Comment: Ohhhh i think thats what it was i see now that actually worked for me.

Comment: Yeah im not going to edit the library code It was a much simpler answer than what I had thought.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every chip must have unique address, and this is doable according to [Microchip's manual](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21952b.pdf) page 8. So, first of all, you should setup different addresses in your hardware layout.

You should also create an `Adafruit_MCP23017` object for every chip you want to use, and setup corresponding addresses in your code.

In this case pins of all chips will have addresses in range 0-15. To change pin's state you should reference to particular instance.

---

Update

This is starting point for you

```
#include "Adafruit_MCP23017.h"
Adafruit_MCP23017 mcp1;
Adafruit_MCP23017 mcp2;
Adafruit_MCP23017 mcp3;
#define addr1 0x00
#define addr2 0x01
#define addr3 0x02
void setup() {
 mcp1.begin(addr1);
 mcp2.begin(addr2);
 mcp3.begin(addr3);
}

void loop() {


}
```

Comment: My hardware addresses are set up but i do not know how to tweak the header code or where replace the existing code as i downloaded the library through the arduino IDE and do not know how to access it more clarification or examples would be much appriciated.

Comment: when you say   _"And the last is that you should create an Adafruit_MCP23017 object for every chip you want to use, and setup corresponding addresses in your code."_ do you mean create or copy the existing class because if so I am still confused at what i would tweak?

Comment: At the moment I only have 2 mcp23017 chips, I am still having trouble as when u defined the addr1 and addr2 as 0x20 and 0x21 it did not seem to work it only worked when I had taken out the addr1 from the mcp1.begin(addr1); and worked when it was mcp1.begin(); do I have to edit the library and if so an example of how to do that would be great I am also sorry if I am not understanding properly but I am still confused on what is happening.

Comment: So, it works only for one chip? Adresses 0x21, 0x22 are **example**, you should replace them with those you setup in hardware.

Comment: Well I am actually using 0x20 and 0x21

Comment: #include "Adafruit_MCP23017.h"
Adafruit_MCP23017 mcp1;
Adafruit_MCP23017 mcp2;
#define addr1 0x20
#define addr2 0x21
void setup() {
 mcp1.begin(addr1);
 mcp2.begin(addr2);
 
  mcp1.pinMode(0, INPUT);
  mcp1.pinMode(1, OUTPUT);
  mcp2.pinMode(1, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
 mcp2.digitalWrite(1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(13, mcp1.digitalRead(0));
  mcp1.digitalWrite(1, mcp1.digitalRead(0));
  if(mcp1.digitalRead(1) == HIGH){
     Serial.println("Led whent HIGH");
  } //this is the new code that you gave me and I edited it

Comment: I dont know if that helps you :/

Comment: well i got it to work using  mcp1(0); then mcp2(1) it was a decimal value it was looking for not a hex

Comment: yes, now clear, Although physical addresses start from 0x20, Adafruits converts 0-> 0x20, 1->0x21 etc

Comment: @ jDo there are no hex or decimal or octal digits, they are just digits, doesn't matter which representation you use. So, yes 0x01 equals 1

Comment: @jDo it supports 7 chips, because mcp23017 have 3 bits for storing user address [manual-> page8].

Comment: @VladimirTsykunov You're right! I somehow got the total pin number confused with the total chip number. Sorry about that. Naturally, the 3 bits wouldn't allow for more than 7.

Answer (score 3):

I share my solution with 7 [MCP23017](http://microelk.azurewebsites.net/Images/MCP23017/MCP23017_PINOUT.jpg) chip , 7x14 pins=98 pins using [adafruit library](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-MCP23017-Arduino-Library).

**Connections:**

```
addr 0 = A2 low , A1 low , A0 low  000
addr 1 = A2 low , A1 low , A0 high 001
addr 2 = A2 low , A1 high , A0 low  010
addr 3 = A2 low , A1 high , A0 high  011
addr 4 = A2 high , A1 low , A0 low  100
addr 5 = A2 high , A1 low , A0 high  101
addr 6 = A2 high , A1 high , A0 low  110
addr 7 = A2 high, A1 high, A0 high 111

Connect pin #12 of the expander to Analog 5 (i2c clock)
Connect pin #13 of the expander to Analog 4 (i2c data)
Connect pins #15, 16 and 17 of the expander to ground (address selection)
Connect pin #9 of the expander to 5V (power) // operation voltage is 1.8 to 5.5
Connect pin #10 of the expander to ground (common ground)
Connect pin #18 through a ~10kohm resistor to 5V (reset pin, active low)

Input #0 is on pin 21 so connect a button or switch from there to ground
```

**Code:**

```
#include <Adafruit_MCP23017.h>


Adafruit_MCP23017 mcp1; // chip 1
Adafruit_MCP23017 mcp2; // chip 2

#define addr1 7 // 7 = A2 high, A1 high, A0 high
#define addr2 0 // 0 = A2 low, A1 low, A0 low
void setup() 
  {
    Serial.begin(9600); 
    mcp1.begin(addr1);
    mcp2.begin(addr2);

    mcp1.pinMode(0, INPUT); //pin 21 on chip
    mcp2.pinMode(0, INPUT); //pin 21 on chip

  } 

  void loop()
  { 
      if(mcp1.digitalRead(0)== HIGH )
      Serial.println("HIGH"); 
      delay(1000);

      if(mcp2.digitalRead(0)== HIGH )
      Serial.println("HIGH 2"); 
      delay(1000);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally got my code to work! in the end it was simpler than i though and i probably did not give a good enough explanation of what my code was supposed to achieve this is my code here.

```
#include "Adafruit_MCP23017.h"
Adafruit_MCP23017 mcp1;
Adafruit_MCP23017 mcp2;
void setup() {
mcp1.begin(0);
mcp2.begin(1);

mcp1.pinMode(0, INPUT);
mcp1.pinMode(1, OUTPUT);
mcp2.pinMode(1, OUTPUT);
Serial.begin(9600);
pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
mcp2.digitalWrite(1, mcp1.digitalRead(0));
digitalWrite(13, mcp1.digitalRead(0));
mcp1.digitalWrite(1, mcp1.digitalRead(0));
if(mcp1.digitalRead(1) == HIGH){
Serial.println("Led whent HIGH");
}
}
```

The problem was that i had only declared 1 mcp and thanks to Vladimir Tsykunov I now know that I needed an mcp1 and mcp2 which can be now seen in my functional code I may run into problems in the future with stuff that i have not revised but for this project it is working now.

Comment: I am totally not agree that library waits for decimal or hex, this is mistake. Library doesn't expects for some particular numerical representation. You use hex or decimal in code, this is yours way of represeniting digits. It doesn't pass to hardware or assembly codes. Processor operates with registers, that contains binary zeros and ones. **Example:** '10' decimal = 'A' hex = '12' oct, but it is still b1010 for processor core.

Comment: So my code is correct but my understanding of the code is misinterpreted? because when i add mcp2.begin(1); and address the chip as that it seems to work but when I use mcp2.begin(addr2); or mcp2.begin(0x21); it dose not I am aware that for the first one to work i would need to define addr2 as 0x21 but even then it still dosn't work.

Comment: You may define addr as 1 or 0x01. I modified my code also, take a look.

Comment: you can not connect more than 8 of the mcp23017 chips as there are only three hardware user configurable address pins on each chip which limits you to the maximum of 8 possible combinations.

Comment: @ChrisPlusPlus *"thanks to jDo for telling me that a Decimal not Hex value was needed"* Just to be clear. What I brought to the table, apart from the confusion over the number of chips allowed on the bus (sorry), was that 1 - you can supply an argument to `mcp.begin()` and 2 - these arguments are not the actual, physical bus addresses that you would use if you manually wrote the chip (they start at 32/0x20). Instead, the library uses 0-7. I just don't want to go on record for saying that hex 1 is different from decimal 1 :D

Comment: Ok I just have been misinterpreting things kind of tired. But you still helped me to fiddle around with some things that i wasn't sure about and got it to work. I think we can lay this one to rest unless you have anything else you want to add. :)

Comment: @ChrisPlusPlus Sounds like a plan :) Happy hacking!